# Can I use a Permesso di Soggiorno to travel from France to India and return?

Tags: schengen, permesso-di-soggiorno

Can I travel from Paris to my home country of India and return to France with my Permesso di soggiorno?

Answer (score 3):

You will need your Indian passport in addition to your *permesso di soggiorno.*  With these two documents you can leave and reenter the Schengen area from any of its member states.  It is not necessary to leave from the country that issued your residence permit, nor is it not necessary to reenter through that country.

Comment: Note that this answer only addresses leaving and reentering the Schengen area. You might also need a visa or a transit visa in order to change flights or airlines at a stopover/layover/transit between your Schengen departure airport and your arrival airport in India.